# What is the difference between devel and runtime tag for a Docker container?

Tags: docker, runtime, virtualization, docker-image, container-image

For Pytorch and Tensorflow, there are tags which differentiate devel and runtime, I am not quite sure what are the difference between these two, can someone help me understand that better?

Comment: Regarding tensorflow, the [image page on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow) points to a [directory on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles) where you will find the tooling they use to build their images and [the different docker files](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles) used for each version. You will see in details what is included in each version. You can probably find the same info for your other image.

Answer (score 69):

Copy from [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA):

CUDA images come in three flavors and are available through the NVIDIA public hub repository.

- `base:` starting from CUDA 9.0, contains the bare minimum (libcudart) to deploy a pre-built CUDA application.
  Use this image if you want to manually select which CUDA packages you want to install.
- `runtime:` extends the base image by adding all the shared libraries from the CUDA toolkit.
  Use this image if you have a pre-built application using multiple CUDA libraries.
- `devel:` extends the runtime image by adding the compiler toolchain, the debugging tools, the headers and the static libraries.
  Use this image to compile a CUDA application from sources.

Comment: Just to put this into context, I guess you need `devel` if you want to use `TensorRT` functionality. Then you don't need to compile the apps yourself, but the library does that for you. Would appreciate, if someone can confirm this idea.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, development containers have all the stack required for compilation of your own CUDA based application, including headers, static files and more. The end result is having a much larger image, but also one that allows compilation.
The base/runtime containers have the bear minimum to resolve runtime dependencies after you application/any other CUDA applications have been compiled. Similiary to how development pacakages and runtime packages work.